# IOS Issue with Publishing (Invalid Swift Support)

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-application

I'm developing a Mobile application for Apple Appstore, and I keep getting this error. I'm pretty much new to building iOS apps, so please help for me to understand what I'm doing wrong here. A possible solution to get past this error would be great.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Beta version of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Xcode are you using? You should be on nothing newer than Xcode 8 at the time of this post.

You can find the version in **Xcode** > **About Xcode**

In future please post text instead of screenshots for searchability.

Answer (score 0):

Incase your project is having swift classes /library:, Please ensure below settings are as follows:

Project/Target settings -> build Settings

```
1. Defines Module -> YES
2. Always embed Swift Standard libraries -> YES
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using 'Save for ios App Store Deployment' extraction.